# What is the easiest way to export Field settings into a .install file?

Tags: 7, nodes, installation

I have a bunch of custom fields on a custom content type. I'm trying to make my module create these fields and remove them on install and uninstall respectively.

There was a previous question and answer on this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/629/2384 However, it is not adequate. The code was not completely presented. The author used node_type_delete() without deleting the content first, and that allegedly leads to trouble later down the line. So I checked the node_example.module as per recommendations on Drupal.org, node_example.install etc. These files provide insight into the structure of the module, but do not discuss all the varieties of fields (like file, taxonomy, etc.,) and how they are to be structured in the .install array.

I have tried to export my content type using Features, and it does produce an array. But the syntax is radically different from what was presented in the example, and I was lost in the arrays and sub-sub arrays.

Is there a simple guide somewhere, that can help me convert my content type into an array specification I can smoothly fit into my hook_install declarations?

Comment: What was the problem with using Features to completely handle the import of the content type and fields? If it's just that they both remain after uninstalling the feature, then perhaps you can use a feature to handle the import, and then add a custom .install file that removes the fields (as in node_example.install). Or have I missed something?

Comment: Well, I would like to save the client the hassle of having to first install a feature, then install my module... AFAIK, I can't package my module also into feature, correct? The client is even expecting this - no dependencies, just 'drop in' the module and work - and uninstall to erase all history of it every being there...

Comment: You _can_ package your module into a feature. Just don't touch any of the feature generated files except the .module file. Regarding clean uninstall, the idea in my first comment should work AFAICT, but I've never tried it.

Comment: Oh? I didn't know that - so when the feature is installed, will it see and act upon the .install file inside my *module*, which *itself* is inside the feature?

Comment: Have you tried Features module ? http://drupal.org/project/features

Comment: @adityamenon The feature _is_ a module. It does normal module things like execute enable/install hooks.

Comment: Yeah, I used Features, finally. By making a dependency, I made sure my module had to be installed first, separately. That took care of my install() worries - I'm still curious about the non-features alternative though, I don't understand why trying that is so painful - the API has effectively no documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some useful resources on how to do this. And you **dont** have to use Features.

- [Exporting and creating field definitions in Drupal 7 blogpost by Joel Stein](http://steindom.com/articles/exporting-and-creating-field-definitions-drupal-7)
- [Drupal 7 export content type and fields blogpost by Kristian Nissen](http://kristiannissen.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/drupal-7-export-content-type-and-fields/)

Features is great if you understand what it's doing (calling Field API in an automated fashion and exporting definitions). You can use the Field API to define, create instances, attach fields to entities -- and then remove them all module uninistall as you need.

The easiest way for me to do this is look at the functions in the link above and use var_dump() on `$field` or its `$settings` after you make it using the Field UI. Then just use the appropriate Field API call like [field_create_instance()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) to wire these var_dump'd arrays into your modules hook_install(). So i'm saying dont create the arrays by hand, create them in Drupal and just copy an export to your code ...

Comment: My response is about Fields as that is what asked about here. You linked a page about custom content types. You can also make content types in custom modules. I recommend looking at the standard installation profile in drupal /profiles/standard/standard.info and standard.profile to see how they define content types and attach the body field to them.

Comment: Are you aware of any advantages to this approach over using Features?

Comment: Sorry. I use Features sometimes to encapsulate configuration ... I also have made entities/fields in custom modules and/or install profiles. It's up to you to find "what works best for you" and your workflow. There is a good API in drupal to do this all in code. Good luck.

Comment: I take it that's a no :)

Comment: Sorry, i'm saying "find out for yourself". Features can be a pain if you dont understand [Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/features_override) and that your features could be reverted without your knowledge. There is nothing wrong with hand-coding a module to create your own entities and fields ... its just your level of comfort in coding/using Drupal and what your workflow needs. I cant tell you what works for you :/

Comment: you seem to think that I'm trying to achieve some particular goal and having a problem. I'm not. I've used both approaches, and am familiar (though far from an expert) with them. My question was genuine, as you gave me the impression you had some specific issues with the Features approach. If you do, I'd genuinely be interested in hearing what they are. Saying 'It's up to you' and 'I can't tell you what works for you' avoids actually talking about specifics. Can you describe some situations where you've found the non-Features approach to be more appropriate? If so, why? Thanks.

Comment: @Andy I'm sorry to say that you are not adding value to this thread. I thank you for your suggestion (and evangelism) of using "Features" - it is what I did ultimately because I did not get tenken's reply on time, but I'm certainly going to use the links in this answer in the future. I don't like that my module has to depend on another module (Features is not core), and an additional file upload the client has to deal with. I'd be happy to create all the things I need right from hook_install() - and the first link in this answer details the same.

Comment: @adityamenon I'm sorry you feel that way, my intention was to see if we could uncover any specific situations where one might choose Features over non-Features or vice versa. I personally believe that would add value. (I really don't want to evangelise Features - it's a tool and nothing more. I _do_ want to uncover its strengths and weaknesses.)

Comment: Sorry @Andy my reply was rude. I have no idea how to edit it to make it sound more pleasant though. Kindly do understand that your opinions are most welcome to be heard, I was just slightly put-off by your repeated insistence of Features usage, despite my question not really being about 'recommendation to export Content Types' as opposed to 'Specific help on exporting content types to .install files'. Please keep contributing, and don't take feedback of n00b grasshoppers such as myself too seriously :)

Comment: @adityamenon Thanks for your kind words, very much appreciated.